# DensityPlot with the same color scale in Show

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to align color scale for continuous plots that have different ranges. Here the color scale exhibits a discontinuity even with the same PlotRange

```
Show[
 DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}],
 DensityPlot[(x^2 + y^2)*Exp[x], {x, -1, 0}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}],
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
 ]
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at `ColorFunctionScaling` option. When set to `False` in your case it gives

```
Show[
   DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 2}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
   DensityPlot[(x^2 + y^2)*Exp[x], {x, -1, 0}, {y, -1, 1}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 2}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
]
```

[image]

An alternative would be to use

```
f[x_?Positive, y_] := x^2 + y^2
f[x_?Negative, y_] := (x^2 + y^2)*Exp[x];
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```